# PHP: Mapping array results

Tags: php, arrays, symfony

The results I retrieve from my database contains an array with cars (`$resultsCars`). The brand of each car has an ID. Var_dumping the array results in the following:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["brand"]=>
    string(36) "2cb4c4d6-b706-e411-8ed9-0050568c4808"
    ["color"]=>
    string(5) "black"
  }
    [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["brand"]=>
    string(36) "2cb4c4d6-b706-e411-8ed9-0050568c4807"
    ["color"]=>
    string(5) "white"
  } 
}
```

My goal is to replace the id with the actual name of the brand. For achieving this I will use an array which maps each id to the corresponding car name. Var_dumping this array (`$arrData`) results into the following:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  object(some\path\here)#697 (2) {
    ["id":"some\path\here":private]=>
    string(36) "2cb4c4d6-b706-e411-8ed9-0050568c4806"
    ["name":"some\path\here":private]=>
    string(4) "Audi"
  }
 [1]=>
  object(some\path\here)#697 (2) {
    ["id":"some\path\here":private]=>
    string(36) "2cb4c4d6-b706-e411-8ed9-0050568c4807"
    ["name":"some\path\here":private]=>
    string(8) "Mercedes"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(some\path\here)#697 (2) {
    ["id":"some\path\here":private]=>
    string(36) "2cb4c4d6-b706-e411-8ed9-0050568c4808"
    ["name":"some\path\here":private]=>
    string(3) "BMW"
  }
}
```

For creating a new array based on `$resultsCars` and with the brand id resolved, I have tried the following code:

```
 $resultsMapped = [];
 foreach ($resultsCars as $result) {
     $result['brand'] = array_search($result['brand'], $arrData);
     $resultsMapped[] = $result;
 }
```

The brand fields in the resulting array, however, contain the boolean `false`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the problem is that `$arrData` contains objects (that contains you values) instead of directly containing the values. I think array_search can't look into objects like that. Furthermore, `id` and `name` are `private` in your object, you may have to use getters to check values... maybe have to make a custom function to search into `$arrData`

Comment: i did not see the Brand Name present in the array

Comment: @karvin.developer the brand is `2cb4c4d6-b706-e411-8ed9-0050568c4806` and is present as `id` in $arrData

Comment: plus `$arrData` contains some private properties

Comment: oh! now i got it thnx @ Random

Comment: where did this `$arrData` came from anyway? the properties are private

Answer (score 2):

You are using array_search, which will return the index of the matched array element, not the element itself. More so, the brands array contains objects, with private varibles, so to access them you must have a getter function, and you can't access them as an array.

for example, you **can't** do this:

```
$arrData[0]['id']
```

If the object variables will be public, or you are using StdClass you can access them like this:

```
$arrData[0]->id
```

Otherwise, you must implement a getter function, and then you can use:

```
$arrData[0]->getId()
```

You can use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function, to map elements from one array to the other. Using array_map, you can use a callback function that will map the brand to the car.

For example, in case you have a getter function:

```
$arrData = [...] // Contains the brands array
$func = function($car) {
    foreach ($arrData as $brand) {
        if ($car['brand'] === $brand->getId()) {
            $car['brand'] = $brand; break;
        }
    }
    return $car;
};
array_map($func, $resultsCars);
```

After that, your $resultsCars array will have the brand object instend of the brand ID string.

Answer (score 0):

change the first line  $resultsMapped = []; to  $resultsMapped= array(); ..

Comment: Those are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

First change the `$resultsMapped=[]` declartion to `$resultsMapped=array();` then change

```
foreach ($resultsCars as $result) {
     $result['brand'] = array_search($result['brand'], $arrData);
     $resultsMapped[] = $result;
 }
```

To

```
foreach ($resultsCars as $result) {
     $result['brand'] = array_search($result['id'], $arrData);
     $resultsMapped[] = $result;
 }
```

hope this will solve your problem

Comment: this is just an derivative description to make you understand which value is needed where you have put the appropriate key and value since we solve the query based on total assumption